# Formula para cancelar boletas de debito

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo los siguientes datos en sql.

```
idImporte   idmovimientotipo   idcuentacorriente             importe                                 saldoInicial
----------- ------------------- -------------------- --------------------------------------- -----------------
2           2                   25089                342.6800                                342.6800
3           2                   25115                341.0100                                341.0100
4           2                   25141                337.9300                                337.9300
5           2                   25162                336.2600                                336.2600
6           2                   25172                334.6900                                334.6900
7           2                   25193                333.2300                                333.2300
107         2                   26354                174.3100                                174.3100
108         2                   26367                172.7000                                172.7000
109         2                   26374                171.0900                                171.0900
1           1                   25071                344.3000                                344.3000
15          1                   25315                320.4400                                320.4400
16          1                   25329                318.8800                                318.8800
17          1                   25345                317.2600                                317.2600
18          1                   25359                315.6400                                315.6400
19          1                   25369                314.1800                                314.1800
```

El idMovimientoTipo corresponden a el tipo de factura

1. Son las de Debito
2. Son las de Credito

El proceso que debo generar es el siguiente:

Tomando siempre el menor idImporte que ya viene ordenado empezar a recorrer y verificar si tengo facturas de credito, si encuentra, tomar el menor idImporte de una factura de debito.

Con la factura de credito debo cancelar el total de la factura de debito, si la de credito no alcanzara deberia de tomar otra mas de credito siguiendo el orden del menor idImporte.

Si la factura de credito fuera mayor que la de debito cancelo esa factura de debito y el sobrante lo utilizo para la siguiente factura de debito.
Debo registrar que idCuentaCorriente de credito cancelo a que idCuentaCorriente de debito.

Las variaciones en el importe de las facturas las debo registrar en la columna Saldo inicial quedando en cero cuando la cancelacion es completa o registrar la variacion que sufrio el credito contra el debito.
El proceso finaliza cuando no hay mas facturas de credito.

Disculpen por no poder presentar un avance, realmente no lo pude conseguir, espero una orientacion de como poder encarar este proceso.